# C# HtmlAgilityPack Xpath problems, trouble finding H4 innertext

Tags: c#, html, dom, xpath

I have a method that will find everything I am looking for in a section of a webpage, except I am getting stuck trying to find an H4 within nodes. The xpath for //div[@class='job '] correctly finds all 8 occurances that I am looking for. But after I try and traverse the 8 occurances I hit problems.

Here is the HTML output of the code I am looking inside.

```
<div class="job_art ">
<div style="background: #444      url('https://a.akamaihd.net/mwfb/mwfb/graphics/jobs/chicago/meet_with_the_south_gang_family_    760x225_01.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat;">
</div>
</div>
<div class="job_details clearfix">
<h4>Meet With the South Gang Family</h4>
<div class="mastery_bar" title="Indicates how much of this Job you&#39;ve mastered.      Master Jobs to earn Skill Points."><div style="width: 0%" class="noHighlight"></div><p>100%     Mastered</p><div style="width: 0%"><p>100% Mastered</p></div></div><ul class="uses clearfix"     style="width:100px;"><li class="energy" base_value="2" current_value="2" title="Spend 2     Energy to do this Job once.">2</li></ul><ul class="pays clearfix" style="width:120px"     title="Earn XP, City Cash and Loot items while doing Jobs."><li class="experience" base_value="2" current_value="2">2</li><li class="cash_icon_jobs_8" base_value="2" current_value="2">2</li></ul><a id='btn_dojob_1' class='sexy_button_new sexy_energy_new medium orange impulse_buy' selector='#inner_page' requirements='{"energy":2}' precall='BrazilJobs.preDoJob' callback='BrazilJobs.doJob' href='remote/h.php?job=1&tab=1&clkdiv=btn_dojob_1'><span><span>Do Job</span></span></a></div><div class="job_additional_results"><div id="loot-bandit-1" class="lootContainer"></div><div class="previous_loot"></div></div><div id="bandit-contextual-1" class="contextual bandit-contextual"></div>
```

It always finds something else like "Clams(Bank)", which I have no idea how. The problem starts with

```
  string MissionName = node.SelectSingleNode("//h4").InnerText;
```

I have tried numerous xpath, like //div[h4[1]], h4[1]. I only need the first occurence since it only occurs once. Where does the problem start in my code?

I need the inner text "Meet With the South Gang Family"

```
public static List<string> GetMissions()
    {
        List<string> FoundMissions = new List<string>();

        HTML_CONTENT = HTML_CONTENT.Replace("\r", "");
        HTML_CONTENT = HTML_CONTENT.Replace("\t", "");
        HTML_CONTENT = HTML_CONTENT.Replace("\n", "");
        HTML_CONTENT = HTML_CONTENT.Replace("\\", "");

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(HTML_CONTENT));

        if(doc.DocumentNode == null)
            return FoundMissions;
        var DivNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='job ']");
        if (DivNodes != null)
        {
            string Count = DivNodes.Count.ToString();
```

Like I said, it finds all 8 occurances fine. I debugged and got the above HTML i put at the top of this, so I think this part is fine.

```
            foreach (HtmlNode node in DivNodes)
            {

                string MissionName = node.SelectSingleNode("//h4").InnerText;
            }
        }

        return FoundMissions;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Alternatively you could try node.selectSingleNode("//div[@class='job_details clearfix']").InnerText;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell that the XPath query is relative to current `node` by adding single dot (`.`) at the beginning :

```
string MissionName = node.SelectSingleNode(".//h4").InnerText;
```

otherwise, the XPath will search from root node. That's likely what cause you got incorrect result with your attempt.

Comment: A period has never made such a difference before in my life. :) I am suprised my code is 99% correct though.