# HTML Agility Pack: How to access HTML attributes?

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

I've following html code:

```
<tr>
    <td headers="header1"><b><a href="www.site.com">TITLE </a></b></td>
    <td headers="header2"></td>
    <td headers="header3" class="centrato">23/04/2014</td>
</tr>
```

I need to store in a datatable:

```
HREF VALUE in "Link" column;
TITLE in "Title" column;
23/04/2014 in "Date" column;
```

I tried this:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (HtmlNode node in tmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@headers='header1']"))
{
  table.Rows.Add();
  table.Rows[i]["Post"] = node.InnerText;
  i++;
 }
```

This code allow me to add all Title in the datatable but I'm not able to add DATE and HREF, can you help me please?

Comment: `Html Agility Pack and problems` is a terrible title. You should try to capture the essence of your problem in the title. Such as `How to access HTML attributes with the HTML Agility Pack?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
//select all `<tr>` that contains specific `<td>`
foreach (HtmlNode node in tmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td[@headers='header1']]"))
{
    table.Rows.Add();
    //get <td headers='header1'> in current <tr>
    var header1 = node.SelectSingleNode("./td[@headers='header1']");

    table.Rows[i]["Title"] = header1.InnerText;
    //get <a> in header1 then get it's href attribute value
    table.Rows[i]["Link"] = header1.SelectSingleNode(".//a").GetAttributeValue("href", "");
    //get innerText of <td headers='header1'> in current <tr>
    table.Rows[i]["Post"] = node.SelectSingleNode("./td[@headers='header3']").InnerText;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**InnerText** just gives you the text between the Tag. to access `Href` or `Id` or ... you should use `GetAttributeValue` method.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (HtmlNode node in tmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
{
    table.Rows.Add();
    table.Rows[i]["Link"] = node.SelectSingleNode("//a").GetAttributeValue("href", "");
    table.Rows[i]["Title"] = node.SelectSingleNode("//a").InnerText;
    table.Rows[i]["Date"] = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[@headers='header3']").InnerText;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: 1. `HtmlNode` doesn't have `DocumentNode`. 2. You need to add single dot at the beginning of your `SelectSingleNode()`s parameter : [sample case for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22903753/2998271)